# Access denied in cloned repository(localhost)

Tags: apache, localhost

I'm trying to start a new project for one of my university's courses and I have run into a frustrating problem.

I have created a repository on GitHub and then I cloned it to *C:\Users\dhmht\Documents\GitHub\ADISE23_it185300*.

Then I installed xampp and edited the httpd-xampp.conf(apache) file by adding
`Alias /MyProject "C:/Users/dhmht/Documents/GitHub/ADISE23_it185300" <Directory "C:/Users/dhmht/Documents/GitHub/ADISE23_it185300"> AllowOverride All Require all granted </Directory>`

Also I did restart Apache after saving the changes I made.
Now I'm going to http://localhost/MyProject/ but I get 403 error
*Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.56 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1t PHP/8.2.4 Server at localhost Port 80*

What am I missing here?

Comment: are you trying to bring up the environment for the coursework? or is this a problem with programming material in the class?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your Apache httpd is running under a different (technical) user account, which has no permissions to access the directory in your user's personal documents directory.

You can either figure out the user account that Apache is running as (Task Manager can help, or the xampp configuration) and give that account permissions (at least read-permission) to the directory (potentially also the parent-directories - I'm not sure how Windows handles those) or use a different directory outside of your personal user's private directory (and still provide access to Apache *and* yourself to that directory.